# Quais as classes das palavras da frase

Tags: morfologia

Quais as classes de palavras da frase abaixo?

> O aluno comprou as apostilas referente a seu curso.

Minha maior dúvida é na palavra «referente».

Comment: O certo é referentes e não referente. A classe gramatical é adjetivo (de dois gêneros, diz a Internet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### O aluno

Sujeito; 
`O`, artigo definido no masculino singular;
`aluno`, substantivo masculino singular

### comprou

Verbo;
Conjugação do verbo `comprar` na terceira pessoa do singular do pretérito perfeito

### as apostilas referentes

Complemento/objeto direto
`apostilas`, substantivo feminino no plural
`referentes`, adjetivo (no plural pois concorda com o substantivo em número)

### a seu curso

Complemento/objeto indireto

PS: se a sintaxe não me atraiçoa :)

Comment: (referente a seu curso) pode ser uma locução adjetiva ?